# Java Robot keyPress crazy behavior

Tags: java

```
try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();

1           robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);

2           robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);

3           robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_3);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

See the above code, I was trying to enter some text into IE browser tag, however I got weird message saying " left hand side of an assignment must be a variable" while debugging into the robot.keyPress line, & eclipse automatically put a number in the front of the line, ie: 1,2,3 instances above.
Any idea? Is it the the web site tag has some tricky security enforce?
Thanks

Comment: It wasn't eclipse that put those numbers there, it was your robot.

Comment: Honestly, I really can't tell what you are asking here. Can you please give us more details? What were you trying to do, what were you expecting, and what did you get instead?

Comment: I found out that the focus was on Eclipse, so it got this weird message. However a certain HTML element: password could not be entered, was the password field facilitated with tricky security stuff?

Comment: Can any guru help with my issue: unable to enter password by either Robot class or Selenium functions? I have to enter manually. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While in debug mode, the focus was on Eclipse itself, that's why I saw this weird behavior.